# Horizontal scroll bar doesn't show up?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

```
   JScrollBar _horizontalScroll;
  _verticalScroll = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.VERTICAL);
   this.add(_verticalScroll);
   _verticalScroll.addAdjustmentListener(this);
   _verticalScroll.setVisible(true);
   _horizontalScroll = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
   _horizontalScroll.addAdjustmentListener(this);
   _horizontalScroll.setVisible(true);
```

I have a code shown above, here vertical scroll bar is working fine, but horizontal scroll bar is not working (doesn't appear on my Swing GUI).

Comment: Does it require to show horizontal scroll bar? Means does your content extends width of frame/component?

Comment: yes , i am extending from frame..

Comment: Actully i am extending from Jcomponent..to clarify

Comment: I believe Harry meant more like "is the child of the scroll pane wider (in pixels) than the frame".  If it is not, no scroll-bar will appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never add your horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the entire panel into the JScrollPane.

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel,
                     ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, 
                     ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

And you can add your listeners using

```
scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(this);
```